# Overloading the [] operator

Tags: c++, oop

I am a beginner in C++. I am learning on how to overload operators. I have created a class **Complex** that represents complex numbers and methods for complex arithmetic and a class **ComplexArray** that represents fixed-length arrays of elements in complex vector space C.

I get compiler errors, that it is unable to find the correct form of operator[]. However, I searched the internet and I am unable to rectify the error. Any hints/tips in the right direction would be of tremendous help.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error  C2676   binary '[': 'const ComplexArray' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator  ComplexArrays   c:\users\quasa\source\repos\complexarrays\complexarrays\testcomplexarray.cpp    7

Here is my code:

**TestComplexArray.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ComplexArray.h"

Complex ComplexSum(const ComplexArray& cArray, int size)
{
    Complex sum = cArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + cArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

Complex ComplexProduct(const ComplexArray& cArray, int size)
{
    Complex product = cArray[0];
    for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
    {
        product = product * cArray[j];
    }
    return product;
}

int main()
{
    char ch;

    const int size = 5;
    ComplexArray cArray(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cArray[i] = Complex((double)(i + 1), 0);
        std::cout << cArray[i];
    }

    Complex sum = ComplexSum(cArray, size);
    Complex product = ComplexProduct(cArray, size);

    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Product = " << product << std::endl;

    std::cin >> ch;
    return 0;
}
```

**ComplexArray.h**

```
class ComplexArray
{
private:
    Complex* complexArr;
    int size;

    ComplexArray();
public:
    //Constructors and destructors
    ComplexArray(int size);
    ComplexArray(const ComplexArray& source);
    virtual ~ComplexArray();

    //Range for the complexArr
    int MaxIndex() const;

    //Overload the indexing operator
    const Complex& operator [](int index) const;
    Complex& operator [](int index);
};
```

**ComplexArray.cpp**

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include "ComplexArray.h"

ComplexArray::ComplexArray(int s)
{
    size = s;
    complexArr = new Complex[size];
}

ComplexArray::ComplexArray(const ComplexArray& source)
{
    //Deep copy source
    size = source.size;

    complexArr = new Complex[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        complexArr[i] = source.complexArr[i];
    }
}

ComplexArray::~ComplexArray()
{
    delete[] complexArr;
}

int ComplexArray::MaxIndex() const
{
    return (size - 1);
}

/*
c1.operator[](int index) should return a reference to the Complex
object, because there are two possible cases.

Case 1:
Complex c = complexArray[3];

Case 2:
complexArray[3] = c;

In the second case, complexArray[3] is an lvalue, so it must return
a Complex object  by reference, so that it can be assigned to.
*/

const Complex& ComplexArray::operator[] (int index) const
{
    return complexArr[index];
}

Complex& ComplexArray::operator[](int index)
{
    return complexArr[index];
}
```

**Complex.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    void init(double xs, double ys); //Private helper function

public:
    //Constructors and destructors
    Complex();
    Complex(const Complex& z);
    Complex(double xs, double ys);
    virtual ~Complex();

    //Selectors
    double X() const;
    double Y() const;

    //Modifiers
    void X(double xs);
    void Y(double ys);

    //Overload binary +, = and * operators
    Complex operator + (const Complex& z);
    Complex& operator = (const Complex& z);
    Complex operator * (const Complex& z) const;

    //Overload unary - operator
    Complex operator -() const;

    friend Complex operator * (const double alpha, const Complex& z);
    friend Complex operator * (const Complex& z, const double beta);

    //Overload << operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Complex& z);

    //A complex function f(z)=z^2
    Complex square();
};
```

Comment: Note that your `ComplexArray` type uses your `Complex` type, but the `ComplexArray.h` header does not `#include` the `Complex.h` header. I haven't tested, but I am very suspicious about this.

Comment: Why the drive-by downvote? This is actually a very well structured question, certainly for someone pretty new. All the detail is there, including the error message. Could be a bit more minimal I suppose, but the code isn't really huge.

Comment: what are contents of complex.h?

Comment: @IanA.B.King Thank for sharing this link. I have it bookmarked, and will read this through.

Comment: your ComplexProduct and ComplexSum should return Complex value

Comment: TestComplexArray.cpp would have undefined class problem because you included Complex.h after ComplexArray. Can be be fixed by a forward definition (unless you forgot to show one)

Comment: @BoBTFish,  
1. I added '#include "Complex.h"' to 'ComplexArray.h'.
2. I added '#include "ComplexArray.h"' to 'ComplexArray.cpp'
3. I added '#include "ComplexArray.h"' to 'TestComplexArray.cpp'
4. I added the necessary return statements to ComplexProduct() and ComplexSum().

The code compiled successful.

Comment: It should be ensured that Complex class have default constructor,otherwise you cannot create it's array

Comment: @Kapil or none user-defined at all. I doubt that Complex  class would need _any_ user defined ctor in modern C++, because it isn't class that got ownership\responsibility, unless you mean boiler-plate approach

Comment: I have a user-defined ctor by the way in the Complex class (not pasted here).

Comment: Please paste your complex class

Comment: @Quasar what for? anyway, ensure that you have proper copy constructor. (people sometimes forget "const" and that causes .. kinda weird code behavior, usually error)

Comment: @Swift you need a default constructor if you are using complex *ptr = new complex[size] and if there is user defined constructor then default constructor will be removed from class and you have to explicitly declare that

Comment: Now this is on HNQ, congratulations. About BoBTFish's comment about "minimal" above, see [mcve].

Comment: @user202729, very helpful & structured, as I am a newbie here.

Comment: @step: Please stop adding the [tag:oop] tag to questions which are not asking about oop concepts. Tags should be used to describe what the question is about, not what it contains. Add [tag:oop] that ask about oop concepts, but not to any question that uses a object orientated language.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need the `size` parameters to `ComplexSum` or `ComplexProduct`, because the `ComplexArray` has a `MaxIndex`

Comment: As a further aside, `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` does most of what you want here. `ComplexSum` becomes `std::accumulate(cArray.begin(), cArray.end(), {})` and `ComplexProduct` becomes `std::accumulate(cArray.begin(), cArray.end(), {}, std::multiplies<>{})`

Answer (score 11):

As you have all pointed out - I was missing the forward definition of a #include.

**Complex.cpp** has the header

```
#include "Complex.h"
```

**ComplexArray.h** has the header

```
#include "Complex.h"
```

**ComplexArray.cpp** has the header

```
#include "ComplexArray.h"
```

**TestComplexNumbers.cpp** has the header

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ComplexArray.h"
```

My compile-time errors have been resolved.

Comment: Nice answer. The most important point is that you must **declare** `Complex` before you use it inside `ComplexArray`. This effectively means you must remember to `#include "Complex.h"` at the top of `ComplexArray.h`.

Comment: sometimes just including into header causes circular includes which usually results in compiler's malfunction. there are cases when you can use just an incomplete type.

Comment: Gotcha! I will do this as a best practice then.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the error comes from operator[], as you can see in the function:

```
Complex ComplexSum(const ComplexArray& cArray, int size)
{
    Complex sum = cArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < cArray.MaxIndex(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + cArray[i];
    }
}
```

You don't return a result. That's fatal.

Comment: Absolutely a big problem, but not actually the one causing the error message in the question. Worth leaving the answer though, but maybe clarify the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

ComplexArray depends on Complex but order of includes doesn't look right

```
#include "ComplexArray.h"
#include "Complex.h"
```

You have to forward-declare `Complex` before `ComplexArray`

```
 class Complex;
```

Code fails at \testcomplexarray.cpp line 7 which is

```
 Complex sum = cArray[0];
```

It looks like you have problem with ctors of Complex. Be sure that you have **NOT** defined such:

```
 Complex(Complex& v);  // that's bad. it prevents to use copy constructor
```

If you need copy ctor for some inconceivable reason, it always should look so:

```
 Complex(const Complex& v);
```

Comment: I added the header file for [code]Complex.h[/code] for clarity. Hang on, I am trying summing and multiplying the complex numbers.

Comment: @Quasar yeah, that looks fine.  to be honest I don't see why you need copy constructor, that looks like Complex written in Straustrup's version of C++. are you doing some error checking in there, e.g. in inti()? If copy constructor just copies fields, then `Complex(const Complex& z) = default;` is enough

Comment: I see your point. The book that I am using declares all constructors explicitly. 

https://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Financial-Engineers-Object-Oriented-Approach/dp/0470015381

Comment: @Quasar ah..and it's just a little old.. unless you use old compiler. C++11 had simplified a lot of things. Although I would say that knowing C++98 style doesn't harm, there are still areas for it. Concern may be that if that book relies on C++0x (03), it may mention additions to language which where removed\changed in C++11.